# Why is this workflow reporting failure?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using the [Start/Stop VMs v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/overview) feature to sequence starting/stopping my VMs. I couldn't see a way to run it only on weekdays, so I added some logic to achieve this (please look at the Update below if you're trying to do this). The condition block is reporting "No inputs", even though it is checking a boolean variable successfully.

The app is succeeding, the VMs are being started properly, but the app is still reporting every run as a failure. Can anyone enlighten me as to why?

Here's a screenshot showing all the runs reporting failure and most recent run which actually succeeded...
[image: screenshot of Logic App run history]

And the condition block itself. I've already worked through the issue of not being able to use the dynamic variable '@true' and having to compare to text.
[image: Condition]

**Update**:
Please note, if you're trying to schedule a Logic app to run on weekdays only then ignore everything else here, below is a screenshot of how to do that. This was unintuitive and I had to have a colleague point it out to me.
The screenshot shows that you need to choose the Week frequency, and then add the parameters for 'On these days' and 'At these hours'. I've also expanded the Run After options for the Function-Catch to show what those should be.

[image]

Comment: Why is the Condition step `cancelled`?  I think you need to show us more of the results of the flow, so down into those scopes as well.

Comment: Do you mean down into the scope of the True block? Or further into the Condition step? If I look at Run History and then Run Details for the Condition step, it just shows that it was Cancelled and had no inputs or outputs. When looking at the same view as in the first screenshot I can't go any further into the Condition step, nothing to click on in that block.

Comment: I may have found a 'solution', will report back

Comment: Thanks @Skin. Mods, please edit the question/answer if you feel it's necessary, I wanted to make sure I didn't steer anyone down the path I went of trying to achieve weekday scheduling with logic steps.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague got back to me about what they had figured out, which turned out to be the actual solution to my broader problem which was trying to schedule the app to only run on weekdays. I'm leaving the 'answer' here just in case it helps anyone else facing the same quirk with Condition blocks.

**Original Answer**
Thanks to @Skin's comment I was inspired to google a bit more around the results of the Condition flow...

I eventually found [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Condition-is-cancelled-No-Inputs/td-p/1287230) page, which led me to realising I was in a similar position, with a Terminate step on both sides of the Condition check (both True and False branches).

[image]

Even though the Function-Catch step was technically being Cancelled, it appears that the Terminate was still being evaluated as part of the flow, and thus the whole app was reporting failure, as shown below.

[image]

I'm unsure if this is a bug or a feature at this point, having not found any official documentation noting this behaviour.

I removed the Terminate step from the True block, left the Terminate step in the False block and tried running it again, and now the app is reporting success. Also, the Condition step is now also reporting that it has an input! I don't understand the connection between removing the Terminate step and the change in the Condition behaviour.
The Function-Catch and Function-Success steps are also both being evaluated now, which doesn't make sense to me either, but the app itself is working and reporting Success, so I'm happy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for, hence why I wanted to see more of the scope objects.  Good work.